# How can i add a second event listener?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, events

so, i have a table attached with an event listener where every time i move my mouse over a `<td>` it generates a rgb color based on my mouse position. I want to create a color palette generator. What i'm having difficulty with is:

**1)** How can i add a click event that will take the randomly generated color, that will then disable the 
  `<td>` from creating more generated colors when i move my mouse, whilst displaying that rgb color onto the `<td>`? (really hope i worded that right...)

**2)** How can i store that selected generated color so that it can be displayed in my `class="color-ref"`.

I've tried adding another event listener, but as i am fairly new to coding, im not sure how to actually make it work. Here's my code

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Palette Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="main-header">
        <h1 id="header-title">Palette Generator</h1>
    </header>
    <table class="container">
        <tr>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref" ></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
            <td class="grid-sqr"><div class="color-ref"></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <p></p>

</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
//===================  GLOBAL VARIABLES  ===================

const gridSquare = document.getElementsByClassName('grid-sqr');
const p = document.querySelector('p');

//===================  FUNCTIONS  ===================

const getRandomInt = (min, max) => {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; 
};

const colorGenerate = (e) => {
    let random = getRandomInt(0,255);
    p.innerHTML = 'R: ' +e.offsetX+ '<br> G: '+e.offsetY+ '<br> B: ' +random;
    Array.from(gridSquare).forEach(function(item){
        if (e.target == item){
            item.style.backgroundColor = "rgb("+e.offsetX+", "+e.offsetY+", "+random+")"; 
        }
    });
};

//===================  EVENT LISTENERS  ===================

for (let i = 0; i < gridSquare.length; i++){
    gridSquare[i].addEventListener('mousemove', colorGenerate);
    // gridSquare[i].addEventListener('click', colorGenerate);
};
```

Here is my project hosted onto github. 
https://ryantavcar.github.io/PaletteGenerator/

and my github repository if needed. 
https://github.com/ryanTavcar/PaletteGenerator

**Thanks so much in advance!**

Comment: Well for adding multiple listeners just add a space between them `.addEventListener('click mouseenter')`

Comment: Assign a second function as click handler, not `colorGenerate` again. In the click handler, add a second class to the cell, like "fixed". Now in `colorGenerate`, simply exit the function if the cell has the class "fixed".

Comment: oh, ok! thanks ill give that a shot and play with that.

Comment: Here's my take: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/1wvy0fzo/

Comment: Wow Thanks! i really think i can learn from that and add more to it :)